# Connection to Github from VS code fails

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect VS code (on win10 machine) to github.
The GitHub Pull Requests and Issues is installed and enabled.
I followed few YouTube guides in which it was mentioned the git button that should appear on the upper right side of the explorer window, in order to add the project to the source control section.
[image]
This button doesn't appear at all.

Any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: can you add a screenshot of that git button? the one you saw in the tutorial

Comment: @tHeSiD : added. see on top, right to the "source control" text

Comment: Do you have git installed on your system? Also do you not see these buttons? https://i.imgur.com/S7HRHB5.png that button is removed i think to add these two. you can click on `Initialize Repository` basically does the init for you

Comment: @tHeSiD : yes, I have git installed. But I think that I did too many trials so now I am not sure what buttons I have and if it is correct. Is there a simple guide to link a specific project in PlatformIO to github from scratch?

Comment: Git is a version control system, if you open your project folder and remove the `.git` folder everything will be back to zero also  did you try this extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=platformio.platformio-ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I post this message, VScode released a new version which makes the connection to Github very simple. For newbies like me that need to establish the connection, you may use the process I use:
1- Create a repository on github, and copy the link to the repo
2- In VScode, in view, command palette: GitClone, then add the link you just copied, select the folder where you want to store the repo on your local drive, and that's it.
3- Use the Source Control button on right, and them stage your changes, commit - and now only push/pull or sync.
Good luck.